# Guidelines Needed for BGP Implementation

Tags: routing, bgp

This is the first time im tackling a project which involves BGP routing and I have the general idea what it is, but my problem is I would need someone to suggest me on which platform BGP is best implemented, would it be NS2 or NS3 (as i read NS3 is the latest so it would seem not much helpful guidelines be published rather than ns2) or maybe there another way rather than using them and i would like to know how to properly setup its environment as well. 
Just to be clear i am quite new to this and i would love to learn more about this stuff.Thank you.

Comment: Without knowing the details of your project, it's hard to say.  More than likely either one will be fine.

Comment: @RonTrunk the detailed project description is here ( http://pastebin.com/iKkn3679 ) . I would only like to know whether which environment it is suitable and where there is more tutorials available for exploration and implementation as i do want to know what im doing in an acceptable way and not obsolete stuff. thanx

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As NS3 is built to replace NS2 it would seem to make sense to use NS3 for a completely new project. There are a number of legacy problem with NS2 that NS3 is set to resolve. However as more people are familiar with NS2 finding support will be easier in the short term, but this is a very short sighted view as this paradigm will soon change with the tide. If your project is new and you plan to support it long term NS3 would seem like the better option. Here is a short comparison of the two:

http://wrc-ejust.org/crn/images/Tutorials/ns2vsns3.pdf

Comment: yep u are right with that @fileinster , but from my exploration in this forum as well as on the web i hardly see any tutorials or guidelines for ns3 rather there are more in ns2 but they are still vague, or maybe u can suggest any gud place to start :)